# having error while jumping in list

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

You are given a list jumps of positive and negative integers which signify forward or negative jumps.

Starting at index 0, you jump to index `0+jump[0]` . In general, if you are at index `k`, you would jump to index `k+jump[k]` Let's say `jumps[0]` was 2 . Index becomes 2. Assuming `jumps[2]` was -1, index would become 1.

Write the function `list_jumps(jumps)` where jumps is the aforementioned list. The function should return the string `'cycle'` if the index will never leave the boundaries of the input list otherwise it must return `'out-of-bounds'`. The starting index is always 0.

```
dm=[3,0,0,-2]

def list_jump(jumps):
    xs=jumps
    xy=jumps
    max=len(xs)
    while(True):
        p = int(xs[0])
        print p
        for i in range (0,max,p):
            print i,"iii"
            p = xs[i]
            if xs[i]=="visited":
                return False
            else:
                xs[i]="visited"
            print xs
    return True

if list_jump(dm):
    print "not cycle"
else:
    print "cycle"
```

I really don't need solution. I just want to know what is the error.

Comment: What is the error you refer to?

Comment: you have no way of breaking out of your infinite loop, so a non-cyclic list will run forever.

Comment: You don't use `xy` anywhere. I think you meant to use it in some places instead of `xs`?

Comment: my error       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/pythonProjects/mm.py", line 21, in <module>
3
    if list_jump(dm):
0 iii
['visited', 0, 0, -2]
3 iii
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/pythonProjects/mm.py", line 9, in list_jump
['visited', 0, 0, 'visited']
    p = int(xs[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'visited'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @alexHall no ,it's just unused variable

Comment: @pstatix see the error up two comment'

Comment: @adamSmith no it's not infinte dear

Comment: @mo.khashab `while True` is an infinite loop. You don't have a way to break out of it (except `return False`) so I'm not sure how you think your function would ever return `True`.

Comment: Please post the error with traceback in the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

note that I would just make a set `seen` and add each index to that.

```
def list_jump(jumps):
    i = 0
    seen = {0}

    while True:
        try:
            i += jumps[i]
            if i < 0:
                # negative indices are legal, but we should exit if we have one.
                return "out-of-bounds"
        except IndexError:
            # we've escaped the list: non-cyclic!
            return "out-of-bounds"
        else:
            if i in seen:
                return "cycle"
            else:
                seen.add(i)
```

Comment: the question is to move in the list to the next list[i] in list depends on the number that is list[i[